# Where to publish very long experiments with updates?

Tags: publications

In most cases, an article is not supposed to be updated after publication, especially with the addition of new data.

However, for very long-lasting experiments (say, more than three years) it may be interesting to publish an article presenting the experimental setup with the data available at the moment, with the ability to add new data later on with an update of the figures (e.g. with addition of new data points), without changing the methodology of acquisition or data analysis.

To give a few examples, the [pitch drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_drop_experiment) was started in 1927 and is still running. In Sociology, observations can span over decades while being analyzed with the same methodology. In Biology, a setup monitoring the behavior during development from birth up to adulthood would have each single run spanning months or years. In all these cases the setup/methodology may be worth publishing well before the planned end of the experiments for some good reasons, like telling the community that this particular experiment is actually running (and provide an expected date for the availability of the results) or simply to have a recognition of the work (developing the setup/methodology) for students or young researchers with a paper for their track record.

So, is there a journal that have a format to publish this kind of work in this way? Or are the authors doomed to make several, distinct publications? In the latter case, could the long-lasting nature of the experiment be a reasonable argument for editors and reviewers to accept the first article as a methodological article including only the preliminary data that are available at the moment?

Comment: Particle physicists publish papers about instrumentation that has not been used yet all the time.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Actually I had smaller-scale teams and setups in mind, but this is an interesting example of a community that publishes the setups without the data. However, from my limited knowledge of this community I believe they publish the results in subsequent publication, not by updating the initial one.

Comment: Also publishing in a sort of sequential episodes is possible. On the title of the experiment 1; on the title of the experiment 2; and so on. But each one must be self-containing and in a way closed.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks for this comment. Would you have a reference in mind?

Comment: @Ratbert lot of papers are structured like that. You can look at the free papers on imaging the M87 Black hole. Or, on much littler scale, in organic chemistry you might have "On the reactivity and functionalisation of cyclosomethingsinine #". The M87 papers were published all togheter. But things like the second example can appears at months or year intervals.

Comment: If your idea and setup are worth a paper, it is just matter of finding the right journal. Note that in principle there could be a set up worth of a pater in Nature. We don't know what you have in mind and its importance.

Comment: What disadvantage do you perceive in making 'several, distinct publications'?